# In Google Chrome for Android, how long until cache is deleted (Cache-Control: public, max-age=99999999)

Tags: android, google-chrome, caching

Since HTML5 Offline page manifests are deprecated and a suitable replacement is not yet standardized, the next best thing is to serve your content with a basic Cache-Control rule to never expire. Especially if your application is small and non-critical.

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=99999999
```

In reality, browsers do not actually store Cache forever, because eventually one would run out of disk space.

I know the exact implementation will vary by browser. Some browser use a simple 'max disk usage' rule for the cache of all websites, and then delete the oldest first to stay within the limit.

In Android, there is a mechanism to look at whether the total disk usage is getting too high and then it will delete the cache of various apps. So in this way Chrome's cache could be deleted.

Barring a disk usage constraint, how does Google Chrome for Android decide when to delete cache items that have no expiration?

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently I was partially wrong about the Android situation. Even if you use `history.pushState` *and* sleep for several seconds before launching the `intent:` url, Android will navigate to the previous page (i.e. the one in which the user originally initiated these actions). This is related to the idea that every app open has to be initiated by a click, and while it is smart enough to allow this after a timeout, or ajax request to be confirmed, there are restrictions.

I would still be interested to know if this could be answered from a non-Android perspective. I suspect there might be a way to use `pushState` and `setTimeout` all completing before the `load` event, but it would be nice if there were a proper way to keep this from defaulting to `location.replace` functionality.